# Multiple languages for dictionary Look up in Spotlight

Tags: spotlight

How can I handle several languages at the same time in Spotlight ?

When a word exists in several languages including english, Spotlight gives me results in english. I would like to have all the results.

For example, 'bras' means arm in french. But it's also the plural form of bra, an english noun. So I cannot find it with Spotlight unless I actually launch Dictionary from the Spotlight results and switch the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

⌃⌘D or tapping with three fingers doesn't work for some reason, but you can show a look up popover from the context menu.

[image]