# How to use several languages with the built-in dictionary without changing the interface language?

Tags: ipad, dictionary

I'm frequently reading texts in english and french on my iPad. I really don't mind if the language of the interface is english or french. Is there a way to look up words independently of the interface language ? So far I'm switching the language in the settings when I need to.

This  is basically this question: [Multiple languages for dictionary Look up in Spotlight](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69480/multiple-languages-for-dictionary-look-up-in-spotlight), but for iPad.

Answer (score 1):

**On iOS7:** the dictionary can be selected from the definition screen.

**On iOS6:**
From my experience, switching the keyboard language is enough to change the dictionary language.

First you'll have to add the keyboards you need (this is a one-time operation):

1. Go to Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Keyboards -> Add New Keyboard.
2. Select all the languages you're interested in.

Now you can use the key that is located to the left of the space bar in order to use a different keyboard (a list is displayed on long press).